# EXPO publish fail. What is the cause?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, expo-publish

I have tried to publish my expo app so I can get started on the release process but publish keeps failing with the following error. What is the issue?

```
Publishing to channel 'default'...

Request failed with status code 404

Error: 

Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (C:\Users\tade2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\tade2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\tade2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:237:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:406:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1331:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update expo-cli - you are using a version that lesser than 1 year and above old and points to a no longer existing endpoint checkout issues with below link .
https://docs.expo.dev/bare/error-recovery/

Comment: I have tried upgrading, or uninstalling my global expo-cli but neither are working. When I do npm uninstall -g expo-cli or update.. it says up to date but expo --version does not change.

Comment: May be support stop for that particular library can u check that once !